# VS Code unable connect to remote host itself

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using VS Code on Windows 10, connecting to a Linux host. Somehow I cannot connect to it anymore. It always disconnect itself at some stage and show me the message:

> Could not establish connection to xxhost: withRevealTerminateEvent can only be called once at a time globally within the app.

I have tried all these things:

1. Remove `.vscode-server` directory on the remote host
2. Kill all the VS Code process on the host
3. Reinstall the VS Code client on my Win10 machine
4. Using a new account on the remote host

However, none of them fix my problem. The strange thing is that the other Win10 users can still connect to it.

Comment: I don't see anything else when googling the error message. I'd suggest that you also raise an issue ticket at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues. Provide as much detail as possible both here and in your issue ticket about how to reproduce the issue. If you do, raise an issue ticket, please ping me here with a link to it.

Comment: Yes. I could not find any results when googling this error message. Maybe this post will help the other people who encounter this problem.  I solved the problem, please see the answer by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason and fixed it.

It is actually nothing related to vscode itself. The warning message is too misleading and non-informative. The actual reason is my ssh auth expired for some reason. I randomly found that I could not ssh to the remote host. The error message is somthing like this:

Bad permission on xx/.ssh

After I fixed this, everything works again.

Btw, the bad permission problem started to show after I have created another user with administrator preveliege.